# Existence of cyclic subspace decompositions for pairs of commuting matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an arbitrary field (possibly finite). Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, and let $A,B$ be two linear endomorphisms of $V$ which commute.
For $v\in V$, define the (joint) cyclic subspace
$$
Z(A,B,v)=\{P(A,B)v\ |\ P\in\mathbb{K}[X,Y]\ \}
$$

**Question:** Are we always guaranteed that cyclic subspace decompositions exists, namely, that there are nonzero vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ in $V$ such that
$$
V=Z(A,B,v_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus Z(A,B,v_r)\ ?
$$

Answer (score 5):

No. An easy three dimensional example has basis $u$, $v$, $w$ with $A(u)=w$, $A(v)=0$, $A(w)=0$, $B(u)=0$, $B(v)=w$, $B(w)=0$. Since $AB=BA=0$, $A$ and $B$ commute. This is indecomposable but not generated by just one vector.

Diagrammatically, this is $u\xrightarrow{A} w \xleftarrow{B} v$.

Furthermore, the algebra $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]$ has wild representation type; indeed, even the quotient $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^3)$ has wild representation type. So it is a forlorn hope to try to find any sort of canonical form for pairs of finite commuting matrices, even ones satisfying these relations. The algebra $\mathbb{K}[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2)$ has tame representation type, but still has indecomposables of arbitrarily large dimension.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for moving the goalposts, but is there counterexamples with $A$, and $B$ invertible?

Comment: Yes. Add the identity to the given $A$ and $B$. Since $A^2=0$ and $B^2=0$, $I+A$ and $I+B$ are invertible, with inverses $I-A$ and $I-B$.

Comment: What would you recommend as introductory references to learn about the definitions of wild versus tame representation type, and find detailed discussions of examples like the two algebras you mentioned?

Comment: You could try chapter 4 of my "Representations and Cohomology I" or the book of Auslander, Reiten and Smalø.